# Cakephp getting all data form left side table

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using following binding

```
$this->FranchiseZip->bindModel(array(
                'belongsTo'=>array(
                    'Franchise',
                ),

            ),false
        );
```

it will return result in below format

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FranchiseZip] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [Franchise] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc 
                )

        )
```

but i have many records in FranchiseZip model where Franchise id is null. it will not return those rows. Please tell me how i fetch those rows in cakephp. i want result in following format

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [FranchiseZip] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                )

            [Franchise] => Array
                (
                    [name] => abc 
                )

        )
[1 => Array
        (
            [FranchiseZip] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                )

            [Franchise] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                )

        )
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you need this? Could you not check for the variable's existence before using it with PHP? I think you're after a left join, not sure what CakePHP would use by default. Have you tried specifying a manual join onto your find?

Comment: ya but it is project requirement. they also want to see data where there office are not available

Comment: Is it just that one field or a whole model? If only one, you could set it up as a virtual field. If it needs the whole model you could specify `Franchise.*` in your fields list and it should return all null if it doesn't exist, provided the join is a left join and not an inner join